# What may be true about the roots of the equation $ax^3 + bx -1 = 0$? (a and b are rational numbers)

Tags: functions, roots

Options are as follows

1. It has 2 irrational and 1 rational root
2. It has 1 irrational and 2 rational roots
3. A ll its roots are complex
4. None of the above

As per the answer should be D.
Let $a = 1, b = 0$
So we will get $x^3 - 1 = 0$.
It has one rational and 2 complex roots ($omega$ and $omega^2$)

Let $a = 0.5$, $b = 1.5$
Then we will get $0.5x^3 + 1.5x - 1 = 0$ which is equivalent to $x^3 + 3x - 1 = 0$. It has all rational roots ($1,1,-2$).

Is this correct?
Also what can be a proper approach to this question (rather than hit and trial)

Comment: $3.$ is impossible. Every polynomial with real coefficients and odd degree has at least one real root. And if $a=b=0$, we get a contradiction. You found an example satisfying $1.$ (complex numbers are in particular irrational) which rules also out $4.$ $2.$ is also impossible since the sum of the roots must be rational (Vieta's rule)

Comment: If you search for an example of one rational and two irrational, but real roots : $$-x^3+2x-1$$ $1.$ is the most difficult part, some trial and error seems inevitable here. Unfortunately, it is necessary however to decide $4.$

Comment: @Peter Yea right. Complex numbers can be irrational. But what about $x^3+3x-1=0$. It has 3 rational roots (1 double root). I think because the question is asking "maybe possible", hence we will have to rule out impossible options

Comment: We only have to find out what CAN be true, not what is ALWAYS true.

Comment: Yea right makes sense. Then option 1 will be correct. But any rigorous way. Like without hit and trial

Comment: $2.$ and $3.$ can be ruled out straight forward, for $1.$ it might help to look at $(x+r)(ax^2+sx+t)=ax^3+bx-1$ and compare the coefficients. But even if we find a solution we still must check that the remaining quadratic has no rational solutions. Maybe, someone else has a better idea.

Comment: Wolfram alpha says it has 1 real (clearly irrational) and 2 complex roots, check [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+x%5E3+%2B+b+x+-+1+%3D+0).

Comment: @Arc Correctly pointed out.

Comment: @Arc hence answer will be 1?

Comment: @Peter Real numbers are complex numbers too. So option 3, as written, is a correct option. Maybe the intent is "All its roots are nonreal".

Comment: @alex.jordan I am pretty sure that this is intented since the other version would not really make sense as the option would be trivially true.

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was misguided, as I took the [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+x%5E3+%2B+bx+-+1+%3D0) from Wolfram Alpha without reasoning over it. That answer is valid for a particular case only. A lesson worth learning.

It is clear that, for non-constant polynomials with real coefficients, complex roots must come in complex conjugate pairs, since the factored form of the polynomial must expand to purely real terms of the polynomial sum. Then, a cubic can have either three real roots, or one real root and two non-real complex roots.

To find out which is the case one must look for the discriminant of the polynomial (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation)):

$$\Delta = a^4 (x_1-x_2)^2 (x_1-x_3)^2 (x_2-x_3)^2,$$

and, in the general case, if $\Delta > 0$ the polynomial has three distinct real roots, and if $\Delta < 0$ it has one real root and two non-real complex conjugate roots. The remaining case, $\Delta = 0$ indicates that the polynomial has real roots, with a root of multiplicity greater than one, that is, $x_i = x_j$, $i \ne j$, or $x_1 = x_2 = x_3$. For the depressed cubic $t^3 + p t + q$, the discriminant is $\Delta = -4 p^3 - 27 q^2$.

For the case in question, $a x^3 + bx -1 = 0$, the discriminant is $\Delta = -4 b^3 / a^3 - 27/a^2$, for $a \ne 0$. Thus, it has three real roots if $a<-4b^3 / 27$, and one real root and two non-real complex roots if $a>-4b^3 / 27$. Since $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary rational numbers, option 4 correct.

Now we examine the case of three real roots, $\Delta \ge 0$. First consider Vieta's formulas to relate the polynomial coefficients with their roots, for the case in question:

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0, \,\,\, x_1 x_2 + x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_3 = b/a, \,\,\, x_1 x_2 x_3 = 1/a.$$

Now, use the first $x_3 = -x_1 - x_2$ to simplify the other two, so we get

$$(x_1 + x_2)^2 = -b/a, \,\,\,\,\, x_1^2 x_2 + x_1 x_2^2 = -1/a.$$

Given that $a$ and $b$ are rational then it follows that either all roots are rational (again, option 4), or two of them are irrational and one is rational.

Thus either options 1 or 4 are correct.

Comment: I deleted my previous answer, as Wolfram Alpha only provided the solutions for  the particular case $\Delta < 0$, thanks @Woett for the advices on my mistakes.